# alternative to dynamic variable name in C#

Tags: c#, global-variables, instance-variables

I am writing my custom indicators within NinjaTrader which has a scripting language built on C#.  I would like to share data between different stock charts, but there is no inherent way to do so.  Each indicator inherits from an Indicator class and of course each chart runs a unique instance of any indicators applied.

For example, I would like to be able to 'send' the current price of IBM to a chart of AAPL.  Conceptually, on the 'sending' chart I need to be able to do something like:

static double IBM = 190.72;

however, when the user changes the chart ticker from IBM to DELL for example, I now need something like:

static double DELL = 9.25;

On my 'receiving' chart I would like to be able to do something like
Print(DELL);

So my tendency is to want to have a variable name that is assigned dynamically based upon the ticker symbol that the user has chosen for the chart, however I know this isn't possible in C#.  So what is a good alternative approach to storing and retrieving data that needs to be indexed by ticker name when there is a practically unbounded set of potential ticker values?

Comment: Use a [`Dictionary<string, decimal>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

Why not use something like a [dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)? e.g.:

```
var stocks = new Dictionary<string, double>();
stocks.Add("appl", 1234.56);
Print(stocks["appl"]);
```

You can dynamically add ticker names and values to it as needed, give you lookup by ticker, and a whole host of other useful features. Any reason you want individual variables as opposed to a collection?

Comment: Collection sounds better than individual variables, just haven't needed to use it before.  How would I set this up to enable me to share the Dictionary contents between 2 separate instances of the containing class?

Comment: It seems as though that's really a separate 2nd question, more relating to how you have your classes and dependencies set up than to how to represent the data. Perhaps another question is in order?

Comment: Although, the answer to the 2nd question might preclude the use of a dictionary as part of the solution, I see your point and will ask it separately, thank you.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this answer as "accepted", since it answers your need for a collection of dynamic named variables.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object:

```
public class Stock {
  public string Ticker{get; set;}
  public double Price {get; set;}
}
```

Then reference all the possible stocks in a List:

```
  List<Stock> allStocks = new List<Stock>();
   allStocks.Add(new Stock() { Ticker = "Dell", Price = 9.25 });

   allStocks.ForEach(stock => Print(string.Format("{0} : {1}", stock.Ticker, stock.Price) );
```